# Ternary operator with append (<<) operator and match

Tags: ruby, ternary-operator

So I have the following line of code:

```
palinwords.select do |x| 
  x =~ /^[aeiou]/ ? testhash[:vcv] << x : testhash[:cvc] << x
end
```

I *feel like* there is a way to tighten this operation up such that the append isn't explicitly written on both sides of the colon. I'm finding it hard to describe what I mean, so here's an example involving `puts` instead of `<<`:

*What I have is akin to* `x == 5 ? puts y : puts z`

*What I want is more like* `puts (x == 5) ? y : z`

It's entirely possible that I'm missing something or thinking about this entirely wrong, so if what I'm trying to do isn't possible, that's fine.

Comment: Maybe `key = x =~ /^[aeiou]/ ? :vcv : :cvc; testhash[key] << x`. What is `select` for?

Comment: n.b. for anyone reading this now - the code above is *not* the code I have (if you want to see it, it is visible in the original post - not functionally different than what's there now), it was changed by someone making an edit.

Comment: @question_asker: The edit might have helped some. If you do mind you can click [edited ... ago](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33651445/revisions) and [click on rollback to restore your original post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17038/what-is-a-rollback).

Comment: @user nah, it's fine - I just thought it was a little strange to make a syntax edit that doesn't affect functionality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this:

```
palinwords.each{ |x| testhash[(x =~ /^[aeiou]/ ? :vcv : :cvc)] << x }
```

Comment: Incredible. I don't know why, but I didn't think putting the conditional inside the brackets would work.

Comment: The inner parens at element reference are superfluous and can be simply written without.

Answer (score 8):

To split all palindroms you could use `group_by`.

```
palinwords.group_by { |x| x =~ /^[aeiou]/ ? :vcv : :cvc }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one more way this can be done:

```
testhash[:vcv], testhash[:cvc] = palinwords.partition { |x| x =~ /^[aeiou]/ }
```